# AngularJs: nested directives in separate js files

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

HTML page contains directive "A" with its javascript file included in the HEAD.

I am trying to use directive "B" inside directive "A", but can't figure out how to reference javascript file to directive "B" from directive "A"

- HTML <-- referencing src="...directivea.js"
      - Directive A <-- need to reference directiveb.js here
          - Directive B

Comment: you can't load `.js` files from directives like that without some sort of 3rd party loader, since angular isn't going to notify the browser that another javascript reference was added to the page.

Comment: Add all directive files to HTML and reference directiveB inside directiveA using appropriate modules for Dependency injection

Answer (score 1):

Declare all `your files` in your page (here html).
 - app 
 - controllers
 - directives 
 - etc...

**Then angular will understand if you inject B in A.**

> Only module explicitly used in html (ex `ng-controller="myctrl"`) will be `loaded` by angular on that page. *Even if you declare (by `<script tag`) 10 files (js) of 10 controllers*. The only loaded will be `myctrl`.

example :

I got an app in 1 file and I inject 1 controller from another file :

```
  //myApp.js
var ngwfApp = angular.module('myApp', [     'controller1_module',
                                            function () {
   //verbose init is ok
   console.log('--> INIT : Hello application :  \'\'myApp\'\' ');
}]);

   //ctrl1.js
  var ctrl1 = angular.module('controller1_module', []);
  ctrl1.controller('myController1NameOnHtml', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    //verbose
    console.log('--> INIT : Hello controller  \'\'myController1NameOnHtml\'\' ');
}]);

 //and so on for all files you need
```

In my html :

```
    <!-- angular app -->            
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_PATH_/myApp.js"></script>

    <!-- angular controller -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_PATH_/ctrl1.js.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it, but then if I want to re-use A elsewhere, I'll have to remember to reference both files.

Comment: I think I understand more. You can declare all files you want, don't worry that only modules you need will be loaded.